# installing MailHog on Linux virtual box to capture outgoing emails

Tags: email, centos, config, capture

I wanted to ease the development by installing MailHog on my centos linux development environment in my virtual box. The php `mail()` function doesn't report any issues (that is, it returns TRUE) but the outgoing mails did not appear in MailHog. How should I set it up correctly?

Answer (score 6):

**Follow these steps:**

- Download the appropriate MailHog version from https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/releases. I use `MailHog_linux_amd64` in this example but you may need a different version. I assume you use your home directory to store your files. In the likely case you don't do this, please, make the required modifications accordingly.
- If your VM uses ip filtering then you should allow the communication through port 8025 with adding a line to the iptable config and restarting it:

  ```
  vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8025 -j ACCEPT
  service iptables restart
  ```
- Launch MailHog with the following command:

  ```
  ./MailHog_linux_amd64 -hostname=mylocal.vbox:8025
  ```

  where mylocal.vbox is the domain name how the host sees the VM. Now you should see some lines detailing which IP addresses and ports it uses.
- Download `mhsendmail` from here: https://github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail/releases.
- Change it to be executable (adjust the path of the file accordingly):

  ```
  chmod 777 /home/you/mhsendmail_linux_amd641
  ```
- Change your `php.ini` to use `mhsendmail` instead of `sendmail`:

  ```
  vim /etc/php.ini
  sendmail_path = "/home/you/mhsendmail_linux_amd64"
  service httpd restart
  ```
- View the MailHog web interface from your host computer (use the host name we used above): http://mylocal.vbox:8025/. The webmail interface of MailHog should appear.
- Test mail sending from the command line of the VM with this oneliner:

  ```
  php -r "\$from = \$to = 'your.emailaddress@gmail.com'; \$x = mail(\$to, 'subject'.time(), 'Hello World', 'From: '. \$from); var_dump(\$x);"
  ```

  It should display `true` and the web interface of the MailHog should display the new email.
- Have fun, send as many emails via the mail() function of php as you want.

**Some more ideas:**

- If you want to override the default IP address and port settings then you should use the following syntax:

  ```
  ./MailHog_linux_amd64 -ui-bind-addr=192.168.56.104:8026 -api-bind-addr=192.168.56.104:8026 -hostname=mylocal.vbox:8026 -smtp-bind-addr=192.168.56.104:8025
  ```
- In this case you will have to escape the settings in php.ini this way:

  ```
  sendmail_path = "/home/you/mhsendmail_linux_amd64 --smtp-addr=""192.168.56.104:8025"""
  ```